# Editing scroll over Div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a site where my title div is fixed in one position as i scroll down. only problem is that as i make it fixed, my navigation button on the left disappears and i don't know how to make it stay where it is.

```js
// JavaScript Document
function togglesidebar(){
 document.getElementById("navside").classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
*
{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-family:sans-serif; 
}

#navside
{
 position:fixed;
 width: 200px;
 height: 100%;
 background:#fb6542;
 left: -200px;
 transition:all 250ms linear;
}

#navside.active
{
 left:0px;
}

#navside ul li 
{
 color: rgba(230,230,230,0.9);
 list-style:none;
 padding:15px 10px;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #7d4427;
}

#navside .toggle-btn
{
 position:absolute;
 left:220px;
 top:20px;
}

#navside .toggle-btn span
{
 display:block;
 width:30px;
 height:5px;
 background:#375e97;
 margin:5px 0px;
}

#title{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 width:100%;
 height:90px;
 background:#ffbb00;
}

#title h1{
 text-align:center;
 line-height:80px;
 color:#3f681c;
}

#photoslide
{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 width:100%;
 height:400px;
 background:#375e97;
 position:fixed;
 z-index:400px;
}

#info1
{
 top:400px;
 padding:0px;
 width:100%;
 height:2000px;
 background:#ef2341;
 filter:alpha(opacity=70);
 opacity:0.7;
 position:relative;
 z-index:500px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Flavour Dome</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id = "navside">
 <div class="toggle-btn" onClick="togglesidebar()"> 
     <span>
         
        </span>
        <span>
         
        </span>
        <span>
         
        </span>

    </div>
    <ul>
     <li>Home</li>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="title">
 <h1>Flavour Dome</h1>
</div>
<div id="photoslide"></div>
<div id="info1"></div>
<div id="info2"></div>
<div id="info3"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now how do i edit my code in such a way that the title div, info1 div and my navside button remain in one place while i scroll? And keep the navside above all other divs?

Comment: Either your CSS is wrong or the SO formatting is. Your selector `# photoslide` and several others also, have a space between # and ID which is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Copy this CSS file to your html page.

In #navside, I have added some adjustments,

```
margin-top:6%;
padding-right:5%;
```

And in #title, `position: fixed;`

```
   @charset "utf-8";


/* CSS Document */

* {
  margin: 0 px;
  padding: 0 px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#navside {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200 px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fb6542;
  left: -200 px;
  transition: all 250 ms linear;
  margin-top:6%;
  padding-right:5%;
}

#navside.active {
  left: 0 px;
}

#navside ul li {
  color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.9);
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15 px 10 px;
  border-bottom: 3 px solid #7d4427;
}

#navside.toggle-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 230 px;
  top: 20 px;
}

#navside.toggle-btn span {
  display: block;
  width: 30 px;
  height: 5 px;
  background: #375e97;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}


#title {
  margin: 0 px;
  padding: 0 px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90 px;
  background: #ffbb00;
  position: fixed;
}

#title h1 {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80 px;
  color: #3f681c;
}

#photoslide {
  margin: 0 px;
  padding: 0 px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400 px;
  background: #375e97;
}

#info1 {
  top: 500 px;
  padding: 0 px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000 px;
  background: #ef2341;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `position:fixed;` along with `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` on each element you want to "remain in one place." Where top, right, bottom and left value are in pixels.